# Query other fields in tables referenced by FK in junction table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, junction-table

I have a "junction" table (`recipe_ingredients`) that I'm using to handle a many-to-many relationship in my database. Each field in that table is a reference to the PK of another table: `recipe_id`, `ingredient_id`, `quantity_id`, and `measure_id`. These are the PKs of the `metadata`, `ingredients`, `quantities`, and `measurements` tables. With the exception of the `metadata` table, all these tables have only two fields: the PK, and a name or number associated with that PK.

I'm trying to query `recipe_ingredients` for all rows that have a given `recipe_id`... but instead of displaying the PKs in each row with that `recipe_id`, I want to display the name/number associated with that PK in that table.

So instead of a query that returns this:

```
recipe_id | ingredient_id | quantity_id | measure_id
----------+---------------+-------------+-----------
1         | 10            | 2           | 3
----------+---------------+-------------+-----------
1         | 12            | 2           | 3
----------+---------------+-------------+-----------
1         | 13            | 5           | 6
----------+---------------+-------------+-----------
...
```

I'm looking for a query that returns something like this:

```
recipe_id | ingredient_name | quantity_num | measure_num
----------+-----------------+--------------+------------
1         | Ground cayenne  | 1/2          | tsp
----------+-----------------+--------------+------------
1         | Ground paprika  | 1/2          | tsp
----------+-----------------+--------------+------------
1         | Olive oil       | 1            | tbsp
----------+-----------------+--------------+------------
...
```

I just started learning SQL, so I only know how to make simple queries to a single table. I don't even know where to begin with this query, except that I may need a kind of `join` statement. What query could I write to achieve this?

I'm using `sqlite3` on Debian.

The **recipe_ingredients** "junction" table:

```
CREATE TABLE recipe_ingredients (
    recipe_id               int,
    ingredient_id           int,
    quantity_id             int,
    measure_id              int,
    primary key (recipe_id, ingredient_id),
    foreign key (recipe_id)
            references metadata (recipe_id)
                    on update restrict
                    on delete restrict,
    foreign key (ingredient_id)
            references ingredients (ingredient_id)
                    on update restrict
                    on delete restrict,
    foreign key (quantity_id)
            references quantities (quantity_id)
                    on update restrict
                    on delete restrict,
    foreign key (measure_id)
            references measurements (measure_id)
                    on update restrict
                    on delete restrict
);
```

These are the foreign tables referenced by the junction table:

```
create table if not exists ingredients (
    ingredient_id           integer         primary key,
    ingredient_name         text            not null
);

create table if not exists quantities (
    quantity_id             integer         primary key,
    quantity_num            int             not null
);

create table if not exists measurements (
    measure_id              integer         primary key,
    measure_name            text            not null
);

create table if not exists metadata (
    recipe_id               integer         primary key,
    recipe_name             text            not null,
    course_id               int,
    cuisine_id              int,
    servings                int,
    prep_time               int,
    cook_time               int,
    total_time              int,
    foreign key (course_id)
            references courses (course_id)
                    on update restrict
                    on delete restrict,
    foreign key (cuisine_id)
            references cuisine (cuisine_id)
                    on update cascade
                    on delete cascade
);
```

Comment: You must have seen this done in some example of some introduction. Also it's a duplicate. Which is to be expected as a basic question. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `join` the junction table with each of the related tables like so:

```
select
    ri.recipe_id,
    i.ingredient_name,
    q.quantity_num,
    m.measure_num
from recipe_ingredients ri
inner join ingredients i  on i.ingredient_id = ri.ingredient_id
inner join quantities q   on q.quantity_id = ri.quantity_id
inner noin measurements m on m.measure_id = ri.measure_id
where ri.recipe_id = ?
```

The question mark (`?`) stands for the `recipe_id` that you are looking for.

Comment: This works, thank you! Do I just use `inner join` instead of `join` so that the query only returns matching data from both tables?

Comment: @NickolasPeterO'Malley: `inner join` and `join` are actually synonyms (they do exactly the same thing). You probably refer to `left join`, which does not eliminate non-matching records on the right side of the `join`.